# to see if item in dropdownList has been selected

Tags: javascript

I would like to know what the best way would be to loop through a dropdown list in html to see if and item has been selected or not.

I know in C# it would be something along the lines of

```
int selected = cmbFamily.SelectedIndex;

        for (int loop = 0; loop < cmbFamily.Items.Count; loop++)
        {
            if (selected == -1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("please select an item", "Please", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                break;
            }
        }
```

how would I go about in doing this with javascript?

```
<tr style="font-size:12pt; font-weight:bold; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:High Tower Text;">
                    <td>Family to join:</td>
                    <td><select name="drpFamily">
                        <option/>-select-
                        <option/>Gambino
                        <option/>Genovese
                        <option/>Lucchese
                        <option/>Colombo
                        <option/>Bonanno
                    </select><font color="red">*</font></td>
                </tr>
```

Kind regards
Arian

Comment: Your C# code looks horrible to me: what is the loop for?

Comment: Do not use `<font>`! It is not 1999 anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you HTML code is totally wrong. It is not `</option>text`, it is `<option>text</option>`

To loop through the options it is as simple as

```
//var options = document.getElementById("selectId").options;
var options = document.formName.selectName.options;
for(var i=0;i<options.length;i++){
  if(options[i].selected){
     alert(options[i].value);
  }
}
```

but there is no need to loop through a single select. The easiest way is just to use selected index for a single select.

```
//var sel = document.getElementById("selectId");
var sel = document.formName.selectName;
var opt = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex];
alert(opt.value);
```

Answer (score 1):

First: [your HTML is wrong.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#edef-OPTION)

It should be

```
<option>-select-
...
```

or

```
<option>-select-</option>
...
```

---

If you just want the selected value, you can get it via the `value` attribute of the `select` element:

```
var value = document.getElementsByName('drpFamily')[0].value
```

This only works if there is only one element with name `drpFamily`. If not, you have to find an appropriate way to select it.

You might want to compare it against the first value (which is selected by default)

```
if(value !== '-select-')
```

You could also add a `change` event listener to the select element:

```
document.getElementsByName('drpFamily')[0].onchange = function() {
    if(this.value !== '-select-') {
        //a value other '-select-' than was selected
    }
}
```